# AFNetworking param serialization error

Tags: ios, afnetworking-2

I'm using AFNetwork like this :

```
NSMutableDictionary *parameters = ...;
NSLog(@">>> %@", parameters);

void (^successBlock)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) =  ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"<<< %@", responseObject);
}

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [manager POST:...
                                       parameters:parameters.copy 
                        constructingBodyWithBlock:...
                                         success:successBlock
                                         failure:...];
```

The `parameters` dictionary is quite complex, it contain an **array of dictionaries** like this:

```
>>> {
    columns = 3;
    rows = 3;
    time = 54;
    invitees = "{(
        {
        email = \"A\";
        firstName = B;
        lastName = C;
        phoneNumber = \"D\";
        },
        {
        email = \"E\";
        firstName = \"F\";
        lastName = G;
        phoneNumber = \"H\";
        }
    )}";
}
```

But both my server and the success block receive a dictionary where each attribute is in a different dictionary, like this:

```
 <<<
 {
    error = "-160";
    result =     {
        errorPostReceived =         {
            columns = 3;
            invitees =             (
                                {
                    email = "A";
                },
                                {
                    firstName = B;
                },
                                {
                    lastName = C;
                },
                                {
                    phoneNumber = "D";
                },
                                {
                    email = "E";
                },
                                {
                    firstName = "F";
                },
                                {
                    lastName = G;
                },
                                {
                    phoneNumber = "F";
                }
            );
            rows = 3;
            time = 54;
        };
    };
}
```

I suspect `AFQueryStringPairsFromKeyAndValue` in `AFURLRequestSerialization.m` but I can't figure out exactly what is the problem here.

Comment: You are sending a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request (or perhaps `multipart/form-data`), but the nature of your data looks more like it should be a JSON request. Is the server expecting a JSON request by any chance? Also, you are using `constructingBodyWithBlock` rendition, but you haven't shown what you're doing in that block. Can you clarify?

Comment: It's a `multipart/form-data` request, this block is adding the file with `appendPartWithFileData`. The (php) server is expecting an array in `$_POST`; is there a limitation about nested arrays in a HTTP request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `multipart/form-data` request is expecting a series of key-value pairs (or files or what have you), but the "value" associated with `invitees` key appears to be a `description` of a `NSDictionary`, which is going to be awkward to parse (as it doesn't conform to any established standards).

You could, theoretically, make that value a JSON representation of a dictionary and manually `json_decode` (if you're using PHP) it on the server side. Or you could make the whole request a JSON request, avoiding the curious hybrid of `multipart/form-data` and JSON (though I realize that's probably a bigger change than you want to contemplate.)

But the `multipart/form-data` spec doesn't contemplate the concept of nested dictionaries.

Comment: I wasn't aware of this detail in the spec, I will use a JSON request. Thank you !